# Python Parallelize a Function with Multiple Inputs

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing, ipython

New to python.  Working with IPython.

I want to do some calculation on a pandas dataframe with a rolling window. The process looks like this:

```
def calculate_avg_ret_t(return_matrix, rolling_window, t):
    ret_t = return_matrix.iloc[ np.arange((t-rolling_window+1),t+1,1), ]
    avg_ret_t = ret_t.mean().mean()  # much more complicated in reality
    return avg_ret_t

return_matrix = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(10000, 10000) )
rolling_window = 21

avg_ret_ts = []
for t in np.arange(rolling_window-1,10001,1):
    %time avg_ret_t = calculate_avg_ret_t(return_matrix, rolling_window, t)
    avg_ret_ts.append(avg_ret_t)
```

The actual function executed within each for loop is much more complicated and time-consuming, hence the need for parallelization. Can this process be parallized, and if so, what's the most user-friendly module to do that?

I realized the potential problem is that the function has to call the gigantic input `return_matrix` in each loop. Should I first transform that matrix to a `R-list` like object, depending on `rolling_window`?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is only dependent on the data in a given slice, then this would be easily parallelized. I would do the following:

1) Split the data set into N sets where N is the number of processors. The sets should overlap sufficiently.

2) Each processor compute the quantities on its own data subset.

You may want to look at using mpi4py in ipython. See for example  https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/parallel/parallel_mpi.html. This would allow you to develop and debug parallel code quite easily.